# Image in horizontal scroll are stretched

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a gallery of images in a horizontal scroll.

The scroll got a fixed height and the image should take 100% of the scroll height.
Images got variable width but should keep his aspect ratio when they are in the scroll.

I made it simple in codepen but it was working without the toggle. Then I tested with my real spec:

- First, it's hidden
- Then on a user click on a button, the gallery becomes visible

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/Liroo/pen/zYYgGWz
The website where is the bug: http://framepictures.studio-push.com/photographie/making-of/#louis-vuitton

This simple (s)css:

```css
&__gallery {
   border-bottom: solid 1px white;
   height: 32vw;

   &__image {
     height: 100%;
   }
}
```

may work (because sometimes it's not) in the codepen but if you check the website link, it is always buggy.

You can update it with playing with the `off` class of the `#toggle` div and you will see this weird behavior.

I already made a javascript version of this bug but I would like to know if there is any CSS solution. (here my previous solution: http://jensingvarsson.studio-push.com/)

EDIT:

Here you can find the bug in the gallery: http://framepictures.studio-push.com/photographie/making-of/#louis-vuitton

Sometimes it stretch, sometimes, just images are cut because the parent div is less wide.

Comment: Can you not remove the `.image` div because then it works.

Comment: Check again the codepen, it's more even stretch :/

Comment: It would help if you showed a screenshot of the issue and a screenshot of how it should look.

Comment: It seems fine to me?

Comment: Also, what browser are you seeing problems in?

Comment: links to codepen must be accompanied by the code in the question itself otherwise this question is off topic for SO

Comment: I'm going to push the website and make it visible, you will look this weird behavior. ps: I'm using chrome but got the same problem in every browser. (Actually codepen doesn't bug everytime...)

Comment: It's edited with a new link to the website where is the bug

Comment: If you take your image out of its div it works fine.

Comment: In the website, it's not, that's why it's annoying

Comment: It does for me, if you inspect it and then drag the `img` tag out of the parent div it works.

Comment: That's the trick, if you change something in the dom in the browser, it is working, but when I code it and reload the browser, it's the same bug. (I tried to drag out the img from the div and my img lost the aspect ratio, but if you add ie.: a position relative to the image container, it's going to work.... but only until refresh)

Comment: I would suggest looking into `padding-top` and the aspect ratio capabilities of it. Instead of having an `img` you can just create a new `div` and give it a `background-image`. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp